# So I got this to append to the output box, but its coming up undefined. how do I define it if I gave the button a value

Tags: javascript, dom

I know this is simple but I'm missing something. I am just trying to get 1 to append when I hit the button but i get undefined even though I gave the button of a value of 1...what am I missing?

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const button = document.getElementById('btn1');

button.onclick = () => {
    output.value += this.value
}
```

Comment: Add your HTML to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what it is you want, but this will append whatever the button says to whatever the output says.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const button = document.getElementById('btn1');

button.onclick = () => {
    output.innerHTML += button.innerHTML
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>1</div>
<button id='btn1'>Btn1</button>
```

If you want two numbers to add together you have to parse them as numbers first.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const button = document.getElementById('btn1');

button.onclick = () => {
    output.innerHTML = parseInt(output.innerHTML) + parseInt(button.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>1</div>
<button id='btn1'>1</button>
```

Comment: I forgot to be a little specific at first, but basically the way a calculator functions

Comment: @laurenceC The second example is a way to do it then, depending on what the output and button elements look like in the HTML, you might want to use innerText instead.

Comment: You also shouldn't use value to get what's inside the DOM element, you would want to use it anytime you're fetching an attribute. So if your button looked like this `<input type='button' id='btn1' value='1'>` you would get the value attribute with either `button.getAttribute('value')` or `button.attributes[2].value`. You could also fetch the DOM attribute of value and take its value with `button.getAttributeNode('value').value` but at that point, it's just adding unnecessary steps.

Comment: That makes sense now. I will play around with this a bit. I never been comfortable with Javascript and trying to get over this fear. Thank you Sam